# What areas of mathematics are taught in a Computer Engineering course?

Tags: computer-science, self-learning

I'm planning on taking a Computer Engineering course next year, I study hard when it comes to math so I wanna know what area of mathematics I'm going to tackle during my course so I can study it beforehand, even if it's only 1 year, I just need to be familiar with it, that's all.

Comment: Discrete Mathematics and First Order Logic. Probably (?) some calculus and linear algebra too. Whatever you'll be studying, I recommend you go through [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: Is that everything that I would be studying in my course?

Comment: If you don't have a choice to choose your courses, then I would say so, yes. You can just check what courses the school you'll be applying too offers. I forgot to mention that Analytic Geometry is also a strong possibility (useful for [computer graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_graphics_(computer_science))). And if you wanna count it as 'regular' mathematics, then you'll be learning Computational complexity theory too.

Comment: Awesome, that really helps.

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient: You might want to look the courses at several schools that have programs like this to see what other things might be of interest. For example, some require algorithm analysis and some have programs in cryptography. For example, check out UCSD, but there are many others. Regards